# mount a file containing a file system as a regular user

Tags: mount, fuse

If I create an empty file and format a file system on it:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=foo bs=1 count=0 seek=10G
mkfs.xfs foo
mkdir bar
```

How can I non-root mount foo on bar? I was able to do it using udevil, but that didn't mount it rw - ro only.

Comment: In general mounting requires privilege. If it didn't then you could mount your own file with known passwords as /etc/shadow and use "su" to become anyone you want. Unix had the idea of a SUID bit to allow *programs* to have privilege, so it is only a small matter of programming to write a wrapper of the mount system call, and then get "root" to give this program the needed privilege. I don't know udevil, but it seems from a 30 second web search just to need the correct config file to allow you to mount something r/w.   Did you try "-o rw"?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to mount filesystems as a user.

- The `udisks` command can do this, but it only works for removable devices by default.
- If you have root access, but want to mount the filesystem as a user, you can add an entry to `/etc/fstab` with the `user` option to allow mounting of a preconfigured specific mount.
- The `autofs` package has a lot more flexibility than the static entry in fstab, and can be configured to allow automatic mounting of images in a specific directory just by referencing a simiarly named sub-mount point in a configured autofs directory.
- `fusermount` (and similarly, subtools like `squashfuse`) can mount filesystem images in some very specific circumstances if configured to allow this.

Comment: Regarding udisks: What do you mean "by default"? Do you know of an option or patch that removes this limitation?

Comment: Figured it out. It works by first using `udisksctl loop-setup` on the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using RHEL 8...

```
sudo yum install libguestfs libguestfs-tools -y
guestmount -a xfs.file -m /dev/sda some_dir
```

mounts the file system in the file xfs.file on the local dir some_dir. Can't tell you why /dev/sda works; the -m is supposed to specify a dir in the disk image that's getting mounted. This isn't an image, but it works nonetheless. It mounts is as type fuse. If sudo is available, modifying /etc/fstab also works as @user10489 pointed out:

```
/nfs/xfs.file       /nfs/some_dir   xfs rw,user 0  0
```

That mounts it as a loopback device.

@icarus, fusermount no longer mounts file systems; it only unmounts. udisksctl asks for the root password. Yes, you have to be root to mount (except for the times you don't). I tried -o rw with udevil; it accepts the flag and proceeds to mount it ro anyway.

I tried gio, sucessor to gvfs-mount, and it doesn't seem it's for this case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).